# React native navigation "TypeError: Cannot convert undefined value to object"

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

I am trying to create a drawer using react native navigation but I am getting the error
"TypeError: Cannot convert undefined value to object".
I haven't been able to find exactly where the problem comes from.

App.js

```js
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native'
import { createDrawerNavigator } from '@react-navigation/drawer';

import Home from './src/screens/home';

const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();

const App = () => {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Drawer.Navigator>
        <Drawer.Screen name="Home" component={Home} />
      </Drawer.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
export default App;
```

home.js

```js
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';

const Home = () => {
  return(
    <View>
      <Text>Home</Text>
    </View>
  )
};

export default Home;
```

[error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qvlpL.png)

I deleted and reinstalled the packages. I deleted the app and created it again but I couldn't overcome the problem

Comment: There is no error in the code you've posted. It would be better if you can share expo link or GitHub repo to your project.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem.

firstly I installed the "react-native-reanimated" using yarn

```
yarn add react-native-reanimated
```

then I added "react-native-reanimated/plugin" to the babel.config.js in

```
module.exports = {
  presets: [
    ...
  ],
  plugins: [
    ...
    'react-native-reanimated/plugin',
  ],
};
```

> don't forget to `pod install` for ios

finally I started the project like this:

for yarn

```
yarn start --reset-cache
```

for npm

```
npm start -- --reset-cache
```

if you're using Expo

```
expo start -c
```

[source of solution](https://docs.swmansion.com/react-native-reanimated/docs/fundamentals/installation/#babel-plugin)